# C++ meta function that determines if a type is callable for supplied arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, template-meta-programming

I am trying to implement a C++ template meta function that determines if a type is callable from the method input arguments.

i.e. for a function `void foo(double, double)` the meta function would return `true` for `callable_t<foo, double, double>`, `true` for `callable_t<foo, int, int>` (due to compiler doing implicit cast) and `false` for anything else such as wrong number of arguments `callable_t<foo, double>`.

My attempt is as follows, however it fails for any function that returns anything other than void and I can't seem to fix it.

I am new to template reprogramming so any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

namespace impl
{

template <typename...>
struct callable_args
{
};

template <class F, class Args, class = void>
struct callable : std::false_type
{
};

template <class F, class... Args>
struct callable<F, callable_args<Args...>, std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>> : std::true_type
{
};

}

template <class F, class... Args>
struct callable : impl::callable<F, impl::callable_args<Args...>>
{
};

template <class F, class... Args>
constexpr auto callable_v = callable<F, Args...>::value;


int main()
{
    {
        using Func = std::function<void()>;
        auto result = callable_v<Func>;
        std::cout << "test 1 (should be 1) = " << result << std::endl;
    }

    {
        using Func = std::function<void(int)>;
        auto result = callable_v<Func, int>;
        std::cout << "test 2 (should be 1) = " << result << std::endl;
    }

    {
        using Func = std::function<int(int)>;
        auto result = callable_v<Func, int>;
        std::cout << "test 3 (should be 1) = " << result << std::endl;
    }

    std::getchar();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I am using a compiler that supports C++ 14.

Comment: What about `callable_t<foo, float, float>`?

Comment: @NathanOliver, any arguments that the compiler would deduce are callable (albeit with a warning) should be valid, so `callable_t<foo, float, float>` would be ok if `foo` is defined as say `foo(int, int)` or `foo(double, double)` or `foo(float, float)` but not `foo(custom_type, custom_type)` where `custom_type` cannot be converted implicity.

Comment: @Marco A. Sadly not :-(

Comment: @keith (edited msg) If your compiler also supports some C++17 features I'd recommend is_callable. Otherwise [here's a hackish fix for your code](http://ideone.com/EAbcga). Be advised that this code has many flaws like avoiding the is_convertible conversions entirely and template arguments well-formedness.

Comment: @Marco A, thanks I tried that already, but looking here at [std::void_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t) it seems my c++ 14 compiler has a problem with the simple void_t definition. Using the suggested implementation for void_t in the link makes your example work on my compiler! I'd love to hear more about the flaws in my code in order to learn. I am very much at the start of my journey into TMP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shorten use of `std::result_of` to do what you want could look as follows:

```
template <class T, class, class... Args>
struct callable: std::false_type {
};

template <class T, class... Args>
struct callable<T, decltype(std::result_of_t<T(Args...)>(), void()), Args...>:std::true_type {
};

template <class F, class... Args>
constexpr auto callable_v = callable<F, void, Args...>::value;
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xJExhM8JNqBiH6ad)

you need to remember that type returned by `result_of` is always the result type of a function you pass to this trait by type. To let your sfinae work you need a method to change this type to void in every possible situation. You can accomplish it by using the trick with decltype (`decltype(std::result_of_t<T(Args...)>(), void())`).

**Edit:**

To elaborate the thread from comments about the possible drawbacks of the solution. The `std::result_of_t<T(Args...)>` type don't need to be equipped with a default non-parametric constructor and as such the sfinae may cause false negative result of `callable_v` for function that result in this kind of types. In comments I proposed a workaround for the issue that does not really solve the problem or actually generate a new one:

```
decltype(std::declval<std::result_of_t<T(Args...)>*>(), void())
```

Intention of this code was to make sfinae work as in previously proposed solution but in case of non-constructable types to create an easy to construct (I thought) object of pointer to given type... In this reasoning I didn't take into consideration the types that one cannot create a pointer to e.g. references. This one again can be workaround by using some additional wrapper class:

```
decltype(std::declval<std::tuple<std::result_of_t<T(Args...)>>*>(), void())
```

or by decaying the result type:

```
decltype(std::declval<std::decay_t<std::result_of_t<T(Args...)>>*>(), void())
```

but I think it might not be worth it and maybe use of void_t is actually a more straightforward solution:

```
template <class...>
struct voider {
    using type = void;
};

template <class... Args>
using void_t = typename voider<Args...>::type;

template <class T, class, class... Args>
struct callable: std::false_type {
};

template <class T, class... Args>
struct callable<T, void_t<std::result_of_t<T(Args...)>>, Args...>:std::true_type {
};

template <class F, class... Args>
constexpr auto callable_v = callable<F, void, Args...>::value;
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/PsdjcYaTYcMPrZTQ)

Comment: I like this. I did try to do similar but failed. Great example (I've upvoted you) :-) In your example I could use void_t rather than your decltype trick, but it's useful to have learned that decltype trick - thanks!

Comment: @keith I prefer `decltype` over `void_t` because it allow you to do custom adjustment... You could for example change any type to int if you prefer - you're not doomed to change everything to void... What is more you don't need to implement anything as you get `decltype` in c++11 out of the box

Comment: Are there any cases where this won't work? It's remarkably simple and elegant. There is a similar version here: http://talesofcpp.fusionfenix.com/post-11/true-story-call-me-maybe

Comment: @keith Well there is a case I can think of - if there is no default constructor of the function result type but it can be easily repaired for this use case by using `decltype(std::declval<std::result_of_t<T(Args...)>*>(), void())` instead of previous `decltype` statement or you could go along with the `void_t` as you suggested. Is there any other cases - maybe but I can't think of one right now...

Comment: ...that's not how you "repair" it. What if `result_of_t` returns a reference type?

Comment: @T.C. Good point but it definitly should be possible to repair it by some tag class... Unfortunetly I don't have computer right now to present ready approach...

Comment: @T.C. I edited the answer. Can you see maybe some other drawbacks of the solution that I couldn't notice?

Comment: /sigh. `std::declval<std::result_of_t<...>>()` is enough for the non-constructibility issue, but regardless `void_t` is superior. There are annoying subtleties with `, void()` - that still does overload resolution and may trigger undesirable template instantiations.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd approach this:

```
namespace detail {

template<typename Func, typename...Params> static auto helper(int) ->
    decltype((void)std::declval<Func>()(std::declval<Params>()...), std::true_type{});

template<typename Func, typename...Params> static std::false_type helper(...);

}

template<typename Func, typename... Params> struct callable:
    decltype(detail::helper<Func, Params...>(0)){};

template <class F, class... Args> constexpr auto callable_v =
    callable<F, Args...>::value;
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sNVO88fEZ9ntwudT)

It's a poor man's version of C++1z's [`is_callable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_callable), but it doesn't handle pointers to members. Other than that, I think it's fine.

Comment: thanks, I've given you an upvote as it's very interesting and much simpler than my code. It doesn't help me understand how I could fix my code though :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your original code is that you're using the parameter pack in a non deducible context

```
namespace impl
{

  template <class F, class... Args>
  struct callable : std::false_type
  {
  };

  template <class F, class... Args>
  struct callable<F, std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>> : std::true_type
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  {
  };

}
```

At this point in the source code parsing there might be no way that `std::result_of_t<Func, int>` can yield another return value, but there might be another specialization later in the file as in the following (*very perverted*) snippet

```
namespace std {

    template <>
    struct result_of<Func(int)> {
        using type = double;
    };
}
```

therefore your compiler should check all of them at the same time before being able to pick up the correct one.

That is also the reason why workarounds like

```
template< class... > using void_t = void;

namespace impl
{

  template <typename...>
  struct callable_args
  {
  };

  template <class F, class Args, class = void>
  struct callable : std::false_type
  {
  };

  template <class F, class... Args>
  struct callable<F, callable_args<Args...>, void_t<std::result_of_t<F(Args...)>>> : std::true_type
  {
  };

}
```

work in your case: they help the compiler solve the dependent type as something that always resolves to `void`. Remember that the code above is a *workaround* and you should rather use `is_callable` (C++17) or study how `is_callable` is implemented and get an insight into its technical challenges.

Comment: Wait, are you sure non-deduced context is underlying cause here and not fail in template specialization pattern matching? I'm not convinced question can be read as you suggest...

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've given you an upvote by way of thanks. I will hunt around for compiler vendor's implementation of is_callable to understand how it works.